# bottom ContextMenu with actionbar sherlock

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using ActionBar Sherlock + Sliding Menu in my project. In an activity i have a ListView. I want the listItem contextmenu to appear at the bottom like in gmail app when an item is selected. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You mean number 4 here?

[image]

That's a split actionbar.

> To enable split action bar, simply add
>   `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to your `<activity>` or
>   `<application>` manifest element.

(From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar))

[image]

To learn about this visit the [contextual action mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) section on the developer guid on developer.android.com

**Edit:**

`splitActionBarWhenNarrow` has been [deprecated](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/11/18/android-5p0-deprecation-splitactionbarwhennarrow.html).